# Why can't I assign this protocol conforming class to a variable of the protocol type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I've got a toy example here that I can't find any solutions for online.

```
protocol Tree {
    associatedtype Element

    // some nice tree functions
}

class BinaryTree<T> : Tree {
    typealias Element = T
}

class RedBlackTree<T> : Tree {
    typealias Element = T
}


enum TreeType {
    case binaryTree
    case redBlackTree
}

// Use a generic `F` because Tree has an associated type and it can no
// longer be referenced directly as a type. This is probably the source
// of the confusion.
class TreeManager<E, F:Tree> where F.Element == E {
    let tree: F

    init(use type: TreeType){
        // Error, cannot assign value of type 'BinaryTree<E>' to type 'F'
        switch(type){
        case .binaryTree:
            tree = BinaryTree<E>()
        case .redBlackTree:
            tree = RedBlackTree<E>()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem here is or what I should be searching for in order to figure it out. I'm still thinking of protocols as I would interfaces in another language, and I view a `BinaryTree` as a valid implementation of a `Tree`, and the only constraint on `F` is that it must be a `Tree`. To confuse things even more, I'm not sure why the following snippet compiles given that the one above does not.

```
func weird<F:Tree>(_ f: F){ }

func test(){
    // No error, BinaryTree can be assigned to an F:Tree
    weird(BinaryTree<String>())
}
```

Any pointers or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the context of the situation this would be in. However, I have provided two solutions though:

**1:**

```
class Bar<F:Foo> {
    let foo: FooClass.F

    init(){
        foo = FooClass.F()
    }
}
```

**2:**

```
class Bar<F:Foo> {
    let foo: FooClass

    init(){
        foo = FooClass()
    }
}
```

What you are currently doing doesn't make logical sense, to whatever you are trying to achieve

Comment: Lets say I'm making a data structure like a `Tree`, so I create a `Tree` protocol. Let's say I have 3 implementation of `Tree`. In some class, I want a reference to a `Tree` and I'll initialize it to one of the 3 implementation I have based on a configuration that I take in the constructor. Does that contrived example make sense? Should `Tree` even be a protocol? I want to be able to treat my `foo` like a `Foo` in my class. Your example has me using an implementation of `Foo` though.

Comment: So is the following what you want?: Have a class (e.g. `Spruce`) conform to the protocol `Tree`. You want to pass in properties about the tree through the `init`/constructor such as `height`, which do what exactly? Please update your question with the example and detail about the example. I will help tomorrow, as I’m going to sleep now, sorry!

Comment: Just replaced the examples I was using with something less contrived. Hopefully its easier to answer it in this form.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo I feel like you’re over complicating it. I would change the tree type to `let tree: TreeType`, and then remove lots of generics, typealiases, associated types, etc

Comment: I'm open to doing it differently, I admit I'm new to swift. It seems that my Tree needs an associated type. Most data structures have a notion of the type of thing that they contain. If I add a method on `Tree` like `head() -> Element` that might make it clearer. You would want to know what kind of a thing is going to come out of that function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying for, but of course it's not possible to do that. from your example, you attempt to create `Bar` class with `generic`. and that not the appropriate way to create a `generic` object, because the creation of `generic` object is to make the object to accept with any type.

Here's some brief explanation of the `generic` taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).

On the first paragraph that says, "*Generic programming is a style of computer programming in which algorithms are written in terms of types **to-be-specified-later** that are then instantiated when needed for specific types provided as parameters*."

it's very clear about what are the meaning of `to-be-specified-later`, right :)

Back to your example :

```
class Bar<F: Foo> {

    let foo: F

    init() {
        // Error, cannot assign value of type 'FooClass' to type 'F'
        foo = FooClass()
    }
}
```

From the above code, it is type parameter `F` which has a constraint to a type `Foo`. and, you try to create an instance for `foo` variable with a concrete implementation, that is `FooClass`. and that's not possible since the `foo` variable is a `F` type(which is abstract). of course we can downcast it, like this `foo = FooClass() as! F`, but then the `foo` is only limited to `FooClass`, so why even bother with generic then ?

Hope it help :)

Comment: How would you change this in order to make it possible to have a reference to a `Foo`? That might be a better question. The only reason I have a generic is because `Foo` has an associated type (which seems appropriate in something like a tree).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems reasonable. The point was to try and have some piece of logic that would determine when the `TreeManager` uses one type of `Tree` vs another.

```
protocol TreePicker {
    associatedtype TreeType : Tree

    func createTree() -> TreeType
}

struct SomeUseCaseA<T>: TreePicker {
    typealias TreeType = RedBlackTree<T>

    func createTree() -> TreeType {
        return RedBlackTree<T>()
    }
}

struct SomeUseCaseB<T>: TreePicker {
    typealias TreeType = BinaryTree<T>

    func createTree() -> TreeType {
        return BinaryTree<T>()
    }
}

class TreeManager<T, Picker: TreePicker> where Picker.TreeType == T {
    let tree: T

    init(use picker: Picker){
        tree = picker.createTree()
    }
```

This introduces another protocol that cares about picking the tree implementation and the where clause specifies that the Picker will return a tree of type `T`.

I think all of this was just the result of not being able to declare the `tree` of type `Tree<T>`. Its a bit more verbose but its basically what it would have had to look like with a generic interface instead. I think I also asked the question poorly. I should have just posted the version that didn't compile and asked for a solution instead of going one step further and confusing everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to this is wrong. In your original example, you would have to specify the type of both the element (E) and the container (BinaryTree or RedBlackTree), in addition to the enum value. That make no sense.

Instead, you should construct the manager to take a tree as the constructor argument, allowing Swift to infer the generic arguments, i.e.

```
class TreeManager<E, F: Tree> where F.Element == E {
    var tree: F

    init(with tree: F) {
        self.tree = tree
    }
}

let manager = TreeManager(with: BinaryTree<String>())
```

Alternatively, you should look into using opaque return types in Swift 5.1 depending on what the final goal is (the example here is obviously not a real world scenario)

Comment: Yeah this is closer to what I ended up as. The lack of ability of use protocols with types directly brought this entire thing up. If I could have just made `tree` a type of `Tree<T>` then I could have assigned it anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype F
}

class FooClass : Foo {
    typealias F = String
}

class Bar<M:Foo> {
    let foo: M

    init(){
        foo = FooClass() as! M
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but I can't imagine why I should need to. In what sense isn't a `FooClass` a valid `Foo` already? It specifically conforms to the `Foo` protocol.. Also, sorry for changing the example types on you, but I get it.

Comment: Your original example was confusing and no one understood the purpose of it. Your problem was it didn't compile. You asked help specifically for that problem. I gave you a solution which compiles. Again, I don't know the purpose of your code. So I don't understand why you voted -1. Thanks.