# How would you model Java's `List` interface in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to understand what problems protocols are appropriate for in Swift and I think this question would be a good proxy for it. We can look at a subset of Java's `List` interface.

```
interface List<T> {

    public void add(t: T) 
}
```

I started off assuming that this must be a protocol in Swift with an associated type, but that assumption [quickly got me into trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615215/why-cant-i-assign-this-protocol-conforming-class-to-a-variable-of-the-protocol). I also notice that the Swift `Array` type isn't a protocol so it isn't obvious that protocols are the default solution here at all.

If you wanted to make a base List type that only serves to define an interface and then provide multiple implementations of that interface that can be used as though they were a `List`, how would you model it in Swift? If the answer isn't "by using protocols with associated types", could the problem be changed in some way to make the answer "definitely protocols with associated types"?

EDIT: I'll include a snippet of something that doesn't translate directly into Swift. What should this look like? We can't have references to protocols with associated types so we can't directly translate this. I'm asking what this *should* be translated into in Swift.

```
class Inventory<T> {

    private final List<T> remainingItems
    private final List<T> soldItems

    public Inventory(){
        remainingItems = new ArrayList()
        soldItems = new ArrayList()
    }

    public void itemSold(t: T){
        // ...
    }

    public void newItem(t: T){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at things like the `Collection` and `Sequence` protocols in Swift as well as the many other protocols that `Array` conforms to.

Comment: The problem with looking at `Collection` is that you can't really use it like you would use the `List` (or `Collection`) in Java. I can have a private variable in a class of type `List<T>`, for example, but I can only use a protocol with an associated type as a generic constraint.

Comment: Do you have a concrete use-case in mind? Generic/protocol abstractions are always much easier to come with by starting with a designed usecase/syntax, and working back from there. `Array` is the common currency of ordered collections in Swift. I found it a bit jarring coming from Java, which aims to only ever use interfaces at API boundaries.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo nonsense, if anything Java is the language with limitations. `List<T>` is inferior compared to `Array<T>` or `Collection` in Swift. Maybe you should ask about explicit use cases, so we can tell you what you're doing wrong instead.

Comment: @Alexander I think you're close to what my issue is. I'll update the snippet to include something that won't translate directly into Swift. Maybe a translation of that will be what I'm looking for

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alexander The example is supposed to represent a class that initializes an instance of a List to a different implementation depending on some hint in the constructor or something. Its contrived, its primarily a learning exercise. In Swift, you can't just have a reference to a generic interface so you can't do it like this. The way I've settled on is using a seperate protocol that knows how to initailze List and pass that around instead of embedding that logic into the equivalent of the Inventory class.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo Well you kind of can, but it forced your wrapping class to also be generic (over any list time), which is probably not what you're going for.

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo I forgot to mention, you could use a type eraser, like [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anycollection)